# *-readme.txt files in ELPA root, what do they do?

Tags: package

I see a lot of *-readme.txt files in my ELPA root. They seem to describe some of the packages that I
had installed at some point. A few related questions follow:

- why do some packages have them while others do not?
- why aren't they deleted automatically when a package is removed?
- is it possible to disable them? I would prefer to save screen space in the `dired` buffer.

Comment: Could you post the contents and filename of a specific one? I don't see anything like that in my elpa folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those files are created when you look at the details of a package from the `*Packages*` list view -- they provide the content shown in the `*Help*` buffer when you use `describe-package`.

You will only see those files for packages that you happen to have clicked on (or otherwise queried) to get more information. You can delete them as they can always be retrieved again.

I'm not sure if there is a way to delete them automatically.

If you want to ignore them in dired, one option would be to use `dired-omit-mode`. You could add "-readme.txt" to the `dired-omit-extensions` list.

Comment: I would be great to auto-delete them.

Comment: @abo-abo Why exactly? Isn't the elpa folder mostly meant for internal use only?

Comment: @T.Verron, I like the `dired` interface for viewing and deleting the stuff that I currently have.

Comment: You could probably advise `describe-package` to delete them right away.